# Expand VerticalLayout width to match Grid width

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am writing a Vaadin `SearchDialog` which contains :

- A search TextField
- A Grid containing search results
- Two action buttons to confirm or cancel

Basically this is my layout structure :

Dialog 
|- MainLayout (VerticalLayout) 
| - - SearchField(TextField) 
| - - ResultGrid (Grid) 
| - - ButtonLayout (HorizontalLayout) 
| - - - CancelButton 
| - - - ConfirmButton

My issue is that I try to expand the grid's  width to it's maximum size. I used Grid::setWidthFull and this code

```
resultGrid.getColumns().forEach(column -> column.setAutoWidth(true));
```

But it seems that the mainLayout width still set to the "ButtonLayout" :

[image]

My technical context is :

- Vaadin flow 14.7 (full java)
- Java 16
- Spring Boot

Answer (score 2):

`VaadinDialog` has a predefined padding applied to it. To remove it (let the Dialog take up full space, add the CSS below to your `shared-styles.js` file:

```
<dom-module id="my-dialog-styles" theme-for="vaadin-dialog-overlay">
 <template>
   <style>
     [part="content"] {
        padding: 0;
     }
   </style>
 </template>
</dom-module>
```

Or add this so your `shared-styles.css` file to make it fullscreen

```
    vaadin-dialog-overlay {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    
    vaadin-dialog-overlay::part(overlay) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    vaadin-dialog-overlay::part(content) {
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. My issue is not related to the Dialog itself. When I set a complex form into a Dialog, the Dialog's size adapt iteslf to it's content. But the grid doesn't. When I set a grid into the Dialog, it's width doesn't change.

Comment: From your screenshot, the Grid is taking up the available space. Or did you crop the image?

Comment: Also, what is the width of `SearchField`? `Grid::setWidthFull` sets the width to 100% which is relative to the width of the parent.

Comment: I never set the size myself, so I think the size of SearchField is a texteArea default size. So My guess is that the grid size doesn't adapt automatically to it's content. That's why i have a scroller.

Comment: If you werent able to fix it, you can show how to replicate the issue so I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

`Grid::setWidthFull` -- This means that you set the Grid's width to 100%, which in turn means that the Grid will use up as much or as little space as the parent layout has available regardless of its own contents.

If you want to expand the grid to accommodate all the contents, you don't want any width setting for it. I can't remember what the default is for Vaadin 14, but `setWidth(null);` should remove any previously set width.

For clearing the size settings in both directions at once there is also `setSizeUndefined()`, but that might not be optimal with your Grid (unless you have very few rows).